# Is there a fast way to get the number of rows in an Excel sheet using ADO.Net?

Tags: excel, ado.net

Is there a better way than

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<xlxsName>;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=True\"";
string sql = string.Format("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [{0}] ", worksheetName);
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    totalCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
}
```

to get a row count from an excel sheet? If possible I'd prefer to use ADO.Net instead of Excel interop